# Trabajar datos JSON con Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Cuando se ejecuta el método `convertir()` todos los datos de la tabla se convierten en *JSON*, pero yo necesito obtener los datos de cada fila en vez de la tabla completa. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Código *Javascript*:

```
function convertir() {
    var table = $('#tabla_json').tableToJSON({
    ignoreColumns: [0]
});
    return table;
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Ajax Post
    $('#aceptar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/fondo_habitacional/guardar_tabla/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"table": JSON.stringify(convertir())},
            success: function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

En las vistas (`View`):

```
def guardar_tabla(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        data = request.POST.get('table')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

---

Tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla la cual yo introduzco los datos, lo que necesito es guardar los datos que yo introduzca en esta tabla a la base de datos..para esto la funcion convertir me lo convierte en json y con el ajax lo debo de enviar a la Base de datos..

Comment: ¿De cuál tabla? Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Ups... edita tu pregunta usando este enlace [edit] y borra la respuesta que no es respuesta. Tienes un ejemplo de los datos?

Answer (score 1):

**In Script:**

```
function convertir() {
    var table = $('#tabla_json').tableToJSON({
    ignoreColumns: [0]
});
    return table;
}


 $(document).ready(function(){

    //Ajax Post
    $('#aceptar').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/fondo_habitacional/guardar_tabla/",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {"table": JSON.stringify(convertir())},
           success: function(data){
               alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           }
       });
    });
});
```

**In Views:**

```
def guardar_tabla(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:

        data = request.POST.get('table')

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Cuando se ejecuta el metodo convertir() todos los datos de la tabla se convierten en Json, yo necesito obtener los datos de cada fila, no de la tabla completa, como puedo hacer eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui yo introduzco los datos y le doy al boton aceptar q esta abajo, luego el me muestra esto, que son los datos de la tabla completa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views**:
def guardar_tabla(request):

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
    table = request.POST.items()
    data = request.POST.get('table')


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
else:
    raise Http404
```

**script**:
function convertir() {
    var table = $('#tabla_json').tableToJSON({
    ignoreColumns: [0]
});
    return table;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//Ajax Post
$('#aceptar').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/fondo_habitacional/guardar_tabla/",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {"table": JSON.stringify(convertir())},
       success: function(data){
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       }
   });
});
```

});

(Soy nuevo aqui, no estoy muy familiarizado con la pagina, por eso lo publique alli y no aqui..)

Yo lo que quiero es guardar los datos de table en la Base de Datos..